# Random noise in speaker with ESP32+DAC+Amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, esp32, dac

We are facing the following issue with our application board based off ESP32 module.
We are using PCM5102 from TI as a DAC running over a I2S interface. The DAC is connected to the TPA3136 amplifier which drives our speaker. Whenever we signal the ESP32 to play a sound, it play the sound with lots of noise and sometimes the noise randomly disappears. I am attaching the schematic of the power, ESP 32 and the codec sections for better understanding.

**Power Section**
[image]
**ESP32 Section**
[image]
**Codec Section**
[image]

PS: This is the exact same circuit (with all the same components) that we use on one of the previous versions of the same board and we don't face any issues. It is our observation that removing TVS D24 solves the issue. Kindly share your thoughts on this. We appreciate all the help that this community provides!

Regards,
Sarth

**Update to this issue**

Probing the BCLK line using an oscilloscope probe removes any noise whatsoever and adding a 1M resistor from BCLK to GND also resolves the problem.

One weird observation is that when the DAC chip and amplifier chip are heated a bit using a heat gun, the noise suddenly disappears. When the ICs cool off, the crackling sound starts to pop up again.

Any ideas on this weird observations?

Comment: Please describe "noise" or record and post it. Probe the I2S and decode it. How is it generated? Bitbang?

Comment: And 'scope across D24.  Is it causing the 3.3V to be noisy (oscillate?)

Comment: @winny "Noise" means junk sounds like something is cracking. The noise is completely random and not periodic. I'll try to find a recording and post.

Comment: @rdtsc Sure. I'll probe D24 as suggested. In general do you think that the TVS diode might have do something with this? our observation is that removing D24 solves the problem more or less but we are unable to yet understand why and how does D24 cause the power line to be noisy, if it does.

Comment: Crackling at random would lead me to focus on the I2S part. How it is generated?

Comment: The [TS0301TE](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2212071830_Shenzhen-JingYang-TS0301TE_C5307903.pdf) shows an interesting chart on page two, where the transfer characteristic has a negative slope from Vt to Vh.  Negative slopes tend to cause oscillation, so just want to rule this possibility out.  Especially since it works better with D24 removed.

Comment: I'm a bit dubious about the D24 thing. Are you sure about it? if it is an intermittent issue did the two things just happen to coincide? if you do this 10 times is it repeatable? If it IS then definitely scope the supplies looking for issues there - preferably with a good analogue scope, rather easy to miss oscillation with a digital one. But still this is not really making sense for me, but that is the only real way that that diode can cause issues elsewhere.

Comment: FYI, the BA33BC0T is a low drop out linear regulator, not a DC-DC converter.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few steps I would go through here:

1. if you have two boards that have this issue, and you remove D24, does that one NEVER do it, and the other ALWAYS? i.e. is the D24 thing repeatable?

if YES:

- check the 3V3 VERY carefully, especially look at where it forms the analogue supply for the codec chip. Also look at the audio out VERY carefully for signs of oscillation getting through, perhaps from the analogue supply. Use an analogue scope for preference! it is VERY easy to miss these things on a DSO. The oscillation you are looking for may not be audio band, but it is likely < 1MHz or so.

if NO:

- it's perhaps not D24. Still do the checks above, but if nothing, look elsewhere. Possibly the I2C data. It could also be some other supply/stability issue. Note that the power amp is class D and these do some magic to get rid of switching frequency. This is all fine when everything else is analogue domain, but if some other component gets some HF content in there, the two can interact and make weird sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on a design.

It seems that the BCLK is not properly terminated so the signal is bouncing.

I had a proper resistor near the DAC on the BCLK. In my case, 300 ohms worked.

The {eating?} treatment of your DAC might modify the input characteristics and stop the noise.

Comment: 300 ohms from BLCK to GND?

Comment: Yes, try from 50 ohm to 500, in my case a too low resistor cause the dac stop working and a high value does not solve the problem